# PST to PDT changes on April 1st instead of March 11 at 2:00am?

Tags: linux, timezone

I got the complaint that PST time zone is one hour ahead for Washington in my embedded device. I'm using tz utility to setup the timezone.

This is the [Los Angeles time zone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/los-angeles) :

```
 2018   Sun, Mar 11 at 2:00 am  PST → PDT   +1 hour (DST start) UTC-7h
        Sun, Nov 4  at 2:00 am  PDT → PST   -1 hour (DST end)   UTC-8h
```

I even updated the tz utility with the latest 2018 binaries and still get this problem, Am I missing something else?

I'm puzzled after checking the change of PST-PDT on April 1st?

```
usr/share/zoneinfo # date 031111002018; TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date
Sun Mar 11 11:00:00 UTC 2018
Sun Mar 11 03:00:00 PST 2018
/usr/share/zoneinfo # date 041111002018; TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date
Wed Apr 11 11:00:00 UTC 2018
Wed Apr 11 04:00:00 PDT 2018 <--- Here UTC-7 to UTC-8
```

---

PST->PDT changes a April 1st 2:00am.

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo # date 040110242018; TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date 
Sun Apr  1 10:24:00 UTC 2018
Sun Apr  1 03:24:00 PDT 2018
```

Comment: P.S. there's usually a UTC zone free of such bug causing crazy time changes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like your device is using the `Pacific-New` timezone, which is a proposed timezone that never became law in the US, and which specifies a switch to daylight-savings time on the first Sunday of April:

```
# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO      TYPE    IN      ON      AT      SAVE    LETTER/S
## Rule Twilite XXXX    max     -       Apr     Sun>=1  2:00    1:00    D
## Rule Twilite XXXX    max     uspres  Oct     lastSun 2:00    1:00    PE
## Rule Twilite XXXX    max     uspres  Nov     Sun>=7  2:00    0       S
## Rule Twilite XXXX    max     nonpres Oct     lastSun 2:00    0       S
```

Some systems have historically ended up using this instead of the correct Pacific timezone, for a variety of reasons; see [this RISKS report](http://catless.ncl.ac.uk/Risks/13.87.html#subj1) (from 1992!) or [this Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815200) (from 2016) for examples. There were some issues with this in the first `tzdata` release of 2018 which may have caused problems on some systems. From [the release notes for 2018c](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-January/000048.html):

> The default installation procedure no longer creates the
>        backward-compatibility link `US/Pacific-New`, which causes
>        confusion during user setup (e.g., see Debian bug 815200).
>        Use `make BACKWARD="backward pacificnew"` to create the link
>        anyway, for now.  Eventually we plan to remove the link entirely.

The `pacificnew` file sets up a link from `US/Pacific-New` to `America/Los_Angeles`, and the `backward` file sets up a link from `US/Pacific` to `America/Los_Angeles`. So in theory the data should be correct, however that will depend on what your `Los_Angeles` file contains.

Comment: I just checked the log messages, the client is using `US/Eastern` and in my dir tree at zoneinfo `$ US/`,  I don't see `US/Pacific-New`. I just have `US/Pacific`.

Comment: Oh, OK; why did you test with `Los_Angeles` then?

Comment: The complaint is that Washington time isn't working so I thought its Los Angeles time and now I got the log message from the client and it says they are setting US/Eastern time.